How Can I Fix this Dark Spot on Marble Countertop?
Have asked a local marble countertop repairman and he has no idea. Unfortunately was a mistake I made within a week of moving into the house :/
Left a lemon there. So initially tried to use a poultice to remove. (baking soda mixture left over night). For some reason, I decided to then use Lustro Italian's Etch Remover to take it out. This is what it looks like now (large dark spot). Would love some recommendations to fix it.


Baking soda as mild abrasive and lots and lots of scrubbing. Assuming the stain is just surface.

See this link for cleaning lemon juice etched marble:  https://finance.yahoo.com/news/clean-marble-plus-trick-removing-170348061.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAADoz6V5tysUqIyCe7chahpcvsyFtsYNYinF-CExLnNAH3tPKATcOdJzSAkjF45uy2Sqvkx4fg3u9sGlF3cUZqE556VPXGQamUI2TCMC86oZJsD1SEImtwvmaD-qfVuFUTWFp5k5gvzDPpJRJ-CfZbPbVD8Qj-SiQ9hfBVGhcvduT

The spot is deep into the stone.   I have seen these before in a neighbors counter. Their adult son left a cut lime on the counter.  They cleaned it with  baking soda and water to neutralize the acid.  Then left it alone.  In about 2 weeks it faded away.
